# How to implement request response mechanism in DDS?

Tags: client-server, data-distribution-service

I am new to DDS,I am using [CyclonesDDS](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds) c++ packages

as I know DDS implementation mechanism is published/subscribe

is it possible to perform a request-response in DDS? like in clenet-server applications?

A client pc will request data then a central pc will respond with data

should I implement it logically in the program? is following way is the optimum method

client PC -> request logic -> client PC **publish to a requestData topic**

central PC -> waiting for requst topic -> central PC **subscribe requestData** check if data is requesting

central PC -> response logic -> central PC **publish data to a dataWrite topic**

client PC -> waiting for data topic -> central PC **subscribe dataWrite topic** and read data

are there callback functions to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to implement request-response logic over DDS. In fact, the [OMG RPC Over DDS specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/DDS-RPC/About-DDS-RPC/) defines a Remote Procedure Calls (RPC) framework using the basic building blocks of DDS. That seems to provide what you are looking for.

For some concrete documentation provided by a vendor that implements this kind of logic as part of their product, you could check out the [RTI Connext User's Manual Part 4: Request-Reply Communication Pattern](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/6.0.1/doc/manuals/connext_dds/html_files/RTI_ConnextDDS_CoreLibraries_UsersManual/index.htm#UsersManual/PartRequestReplyPattern.htm#partrequestreplypattern_1377435071_920452%3FTocPath%3DPart%25204%253A%2520Request-Reply%2520Communication%2520Pattern%7C_____0).

Comment: is it possible to use them with eclipse CycloneDDS c++?

Comment: the implementation in the doc provided is for opendds isn't it?

Comment: No, that user's manual is not for OpenDDS but for Connext DDS. If you were referring to the other document: that is a standards specification so independent of any implementation or vendor.

Comment: OMG RPC Over DDS specification we have to code the rest of the procedure for each implementation in header files isn't it?  I meant we have to code source .cpp program since only method declaration is in those header files

Comment: Speaking for RTI's implementation only: no, you do not have to implement the procedures yourself. The infrastructure takes care of that. For an impression of what your code could look like, you could check out [Request-Reply Examples](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/6.0.1/doc/api/connext_dds/api_cpp/group__RequestReplyExampleModule.html)